# Injecting service with PostContstruct into a taglib

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, taglib

I have a service with a PostConstruct annotated init method to ensure that it does not run until dependency injection has completed.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
     // Create some datasources on the fly
     MyDomain.list().each {
          createDataSource(it)
     }
}
```

I now have a need to inject this service into taglib, but the application will not boot with the following error..

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.me.MyDomain] was
>   used outside of a Grails application

The stacktrace specifically points to the usage above and of course it boots fine when I remove.
Does anyone know of a 'credible' way around this?

Comment: Try removing 'private'

Comment: put the code into `withTransaction{ }`

Comment: @bassmartin Tried, no dice. Same error. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @injecteer Tried, no dice. Same error. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: try `withSession{}`

Comment: @injecteer No dice. :-(

Answer (score 0):

try like:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    Domain.withNewSession {
        println Domain.count
    }
}
```

or

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    Domain.withTransaction {
        println Domain.count
    }
}
```